# Obscuring Customer Names,

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am writing an excel equation that would take an alpha numeric input of random length and output the information obscured. My biggest problem is the the data set can have multiple spaces at varying lengths. I also need to retain a handful of special characters. No macros please. I also do not have access to outside programs (even if they come with Windows).

[image]

Comment: This should be done at source which is producing the excel or you need to write a program outside excel to do this.

Comment: Its possible by formula for sure, though your current question lacks your own attempt and a description of where you got stuck. It's also great if you have examples with those special characters you talk about.

Answer (score 0):

As Asdfg mentioned, doing this at the source is likely much easier. Here's a crazy way of doing this in excel. You can combine some of these steps to shorten, but I did it this way to better illustrate the process. Condense some steps if you wish.

First, I separated Input into their own columns (text to columns, space delimited). This is noted as columns A through E.

Columns G through K are counting the length of each cell in A through E.

```
G2 formula: =LEN(a2)
```

Columns M through Q are simply returning the first character from columns A through E. If the cell is blank, we return nothing.

```
M2 formula: =IF(ISBLANK(A2),"",LEFT(A2,1))
```

Columns S through W counts the number of x's we need.

```
S2 formula: =IF(ISBLANK(A2),"",REPT("x",G2-1))
```

Columns Y through AB will be used to add spacing between words.

```
Y2 formula: =IF(ISBLANK(B2),""," ")
```

Drag all your formulas across and down for each section. Lastly, column AD is your output.

```
AD2 formula: =CONCAT(M2,S2,Y2,N2,T2,Z2,O2,U2,AA2,P2,V2,AB2,Q2,W2)
```

I know, this is a silly way to do this, but you can shorten some of these steps and condense into longer formulas.

[image]

Comment: Agreed at source would be easier, but the source is a canned program and cannot be edited. I know the "winded" approach via concats but was trying to avoid that because my data set is very larger and some names span out to column AAC when delimited. However, I appreciate the effort and time you took to explain. I am mainly getting hung up on the multiple spaces part. The below code works with one space.

=LEFT(A8,1)&REPT("x",FIND(" ",A8)-2)&" "&MID(A8,FIND(" ",A8)+1,1)&REPT("x",(LEN(A8)-LEN(LEFT(A8,1)&REPT("x",FIND(" ",A8)-2)&" "&MID(A8,FIND(" ",A8)+1,1))))